# what is the item identifier in python-amazon-product-api?

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, lookup

Here is the sample code from the [python-amazon-product-api](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html)

```
>>> api = API(locale='uk')
>>> result = api.item_lookup('B006H3MIV8')
>>> for item in result.Items.Item:
...     print '%s (%s) in group %s' % (
...         item.ItemAttributes.Title, item.ASIN)
... 
Chimes of Freedom: The Songs of Bob Dylan (B006H3MIV8)
```

what I don't understand is the `Identifier` used for the `item_lookup()`. My idea is to get reviews
for some product as shown here, but I want to use a product name, instead of identifer. say for example: `Bamboo stylus`. How can I achieve this?

```
>>> api.item_lookup('0316067938', ResponseGroup='Reviews',
...     TruncateReviewsAt=256, IncludeReviewsSummary=False)
```

EDIT:
I tried this: but it throws `AttributeError: no such child`

```
for item in api.item_search('DVD', Actor="Keanu Reaves",limit=10):
    print '%s: "%s"' % (item.ItemAttributes.Identifier,
                        item.ItemAttributes.Title)
```

I tried this: but I get a different error:

`mazonproduct.errors.AWSError: AWS.MinimumParameterRequirement: Your request should have atleast 1 of the following parameters: 'Keywords','Title','Power','BrowseNode','Artist','Author','Actor','Director','AudienceRating','Manufacturer','MusicLabel','Composer','Publisher','Brand','Conductor','Orchestra','TextStream','Cuisine','City','Neighborhood'.`

```
for item in api.item_search('Blended', keywords="Keanu Reaves"):
    print '%s: "%s"' % (item.ItemAttributes.Actor,
                    item.ItemAttributes.Title)
```

Please note that I do have `keywords` in the `parameter request`

Comment: You do see that `Keywords` starts with capital K and you wrote `keywords` with a small k, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`item_search`](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/operations.html#amazonproduct.api.API.item_search). `Bamboo stylus` is too generic a term to identify a single product. The identifier is kind of like a Primary key. So first search for the product using `item_search`, pick up your item and then fetch reviews using that item's identifier. E.g. -

```
>>> api.item_search('Blended', Keywords='Mustang')
```

List of parameters you can send as `query` are listed [in the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html).

Comment: how do I get Identifier for Bamboo Stylus with price less than $20 using item_search?

Comment: You can see the parameters you can pass to `item_search` here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html . Apply what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I can see many useful parameters that I can use for filtering, but how would I extract the 'Identifier' from the search.

Comment: Just call item_search. Each item would have the identifier property.

Comment: You need to debug it yourself. See what the API is returning and what attributes it has.

Comment: even the `blended` that  you suggested, throws error which I posted above